# TypeScript code quality with Sonar : code duplication, cyclomatic complexity

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

We recently adopted TypeScript as our official frontend programming langage for the whole company, because of all of the language's qualities, but we are facing a potential showstopper : Sonar support for the language. This is our main code quality tracking tool, used for years on many Java projects.

Last time we checked, there were no "official" support for TypeScript (at least, not as officially supported as java or javascript).

By using pablissimo SonarTSPlugin plugin and approach, we are able to compute and follow code coverage (some examples from pablissimo https://sonar.pablissimo.com/projects). But we are missing some critical indicators, like code duplication, cyclomatic complexity... those indicators are fundamental because we are outsourcing a lot of developments and they historically saved a lot of troubles on Java projects.

Does anybody have the same problem, and what are your approach to solve this important code quality problem ?

Comment: Hey, have you found anything on this?

Comment: No, absolutely not... :(

Comment: Ok, so, according to a rumor heard on Devoxxx paris, there will be typescript supports added to sonar this year. Finger crossed !

Comment: i guess now it is supported. https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/typescript/